# How do I make an "IF" statement in a computed property of an Entity in Lightswitch C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-lightswitch

I am trying to calculate the % of the poverty level give income, number of people in a household, and the federal guidelines.  The code that I use in Access with the expression builder (VB I believe) is:

```
IIf([NumberInHousehold]>=1,([AnnualHouseHoldIncome]/(7880+([NumberInHousehold]*4180))),0)
```

Is there a c# equivalent? The NumberInHouseHold has a datatype of "integer" and the datatype for AnnualHouseHoldIncome is "Money". The field to be computed is also "integer".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most direct equivalent to the VBA (and VB.Net) IIf() function is the "?:
" operator (typically known as the "ternary" or "conditional" operator), e.g.:

```
result = numberInHousehold >= 1
    ? (annualHouseholdIncome / (7880 + (numberInHousehold * 4180)))
    : 0;
```

Note that the ternary operator will only evaluate the result branch that it uses, whereas IIf() is a function that evaluates all of its arguments regardless of the truth of the condition.  Most of the time, the ternary operator's behavior is what you want, but it is different from IIf().

Comment: I added this code with Method editor, it saves properly and the solution publishes with no problems but when I look at the screen the "PercentFPL" field displays nothing;Not even a zero.

Comment: Actually, by adding nothing then NumberInHouseHold Field a zero is written to the computed field.

Comment: Null values in either the NumberInHousehold or AnnualHouseholdIncome field, perhaps?

Comment: Yes, when I leave the NumberInHousehold field blank a Zero is computed. However, If I put any number in the  NumberInHousehold field the computed field remains blank instead of writing in the calculation.

Comment: That's odd.  It's more or less the opposite of what I would have expected.  One other note: in VB, division is floating point by default (there is a separate integer division operator).  In C#, division of all integers is an integer operation, so depending on whether this is what you want, you may want to add a cast to double on annualHouseholdIncome or make the constants 7880.0 and 4180.0.

Comment: I tried making the NumberInHousehold , annualHouseholdIncome and the computed fields double, decimal and int.  In double and decimal the same behavior i.e. if the Numberinhousehold was blank, a zero would return.  If all the fields where int the computed field would come up with a zero regardless if the NumberInHouseHold was blank or had numbers in it.  Adding .0 to the constants made no difference.  I feel like it is close but I just cannot find the right combination.  I do not know what you mean by "Cast" unless that just means setting data type.

Comment: By a cast to double, I mean, "(double)annualHouseholdIncome".  It's the rough equivalent of CDbl in VB.Net.  Do you have any ability to step through the code in a debugger and see what it's doing?  Whenever I see surprising behavior, it's because I either didn't completely understand the tool I was using, or because the inputs where different from what I expected.